# How is my breadth first search algorithm finding the shortest path in my tutorial example below

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I understand the basics of how a breadth-first search works. It utilizes a queue data structure to find adjacent vertices level by level.

My issue is in understanding how to find the shortest path between two vertices. In the example below, we assign newly visited vertices along with their edge to an array called **edgeTo**, but my question is how is the data stored? Is it a two-dimensional array? And how is it retrieved with the **pathTo** function?

The **for loop** in the **pathTo** function looks a bit odd to me, certainly because I might be new to it.  How does this get the shortest path and how is the data structured or how is it saving the edges?

```
// add this to Graph class
this.edgeTo = [];
// bfs function
function bfs(s) {
    var queue = [];
    this.marked[s] = true;
    queue.push(s); // add to back of queue
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        var v = queue.shift(); // remove from front of queue
        if (v == undefined) {
            print("Visited vertex: " + v);
        }
        for each(var w in this.adj[v]) {
            if (!this.marked[w]) {
                this.edgeTo[w] = v;
                this.marked[w] = true;
                queue.push(w);
            }
        }
    }
}

function pathTo(v) {
    var source = 0;
    if (!this.hasPathTo(v)) {
        return undefined;
    }
    var path = [];
    for (var i = v; i != source; i = this.edgeTo[i]) { // this for loop is new to me 
        path.push(i);
    }
    path.push(s);
    return path;
}

function hasPathTo(v) {
    return this.marked[v];
}
```

Comment: I can explain step by step how a BFS works/how data is stored. Is this what you are looking for? Or are you looking for help with your code not working correctly? 

Just looking for clarity prior to typing it all

Comment: the code works fine, i need help with how it finds the shortest path, specifically  how it stores edges and how it loops through  them in the pathTo function above , the loop seems odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.edgeTo` is a simple array.

The BFS starts at the source vertex, and when it discovers a new vertex `i`, it sets `edgeTo[i]` to the *predecessor* vertex, which must necessarily be one step *closer* to the source.

In the `pathTo` function, the `for` loop follows the chain of `edgeTo` links from `v` back to the source.  This enumerates the shortest path in *reverse*.  These vertexes are appended to `path` as they are found.

`pathTo` then returns the path in reverse order, which is a little odd.  A more  usual implementation would reverse `path` before returning it, so that it would start at `source` and end at `v`.  This function seems to be a little bugged in other ways, too.  Maybe you're still working on it...